# PHP Y MySql guarda en local pero no en el hosting

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo la siguiente llamada Ajax a un archivo php que realiza el insert a la base de datos mysql, el problema es que me funciona en local con xampp pero en el hosting el ajax pasa directo al else en el success.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../negocio/n_remuneraciones.php',
        contentType: false,
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 'Guardado correctamente!') {           
              guardarbonos(remuid);
              $('#view_remuneraciones').load('../negocio/view_remuneraciones.php');
              
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        }
    });
```

```
 $query = "insert into  ******************

  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        if($result == true){
        echo "Guardado correctamente!";
        }else{
        echo "Error al guardar";
        }
```

Comment: Te fijaste que la cadena de conexión sea correcta? Host, Usuario, Contraseña y puerto (asumo que esto debe funcionar) pero... revisa que el usuario tenga permisos suficientes en la base de datos para INSERT o UPDATE.

Comment: Mejor, en el caso de error (en tiempo de desarrollo, claro), prueba a modificar el mensaje y déjalo así para tener algo más de información... `echo "Error al guardar (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;` Y en función de eso (del error que te indica) se puede saber algo más para solucionarlo.

Comment: Y por cierto... dinos si añadiendo `async: false,` a las opciones del ajax se te resuelve el problema del servidor. Y no entro en profundidades de llamadas asíncronas que desaparecerán, etc., etc.